# What is the numerical norm for an Ideal?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading this text on Algebraic Number theory:  (https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf, pg.68). They state the following:

> Let $\alpha$ be a nonzero ideal in the ring of integers $\mathscr{O}_{K}$ of a number field $K$. Then $\alpha$ is of **finite index** in $\mathscr{O}_{K}$ and we let $\mathbb{N}\alpha$, **the numerical norm of** $\alpha$ be this index: 
>   $$ \mathbb{N}\alpha  = (\mathscr{O}_{K} : \alpha )$$

Just exactly what index are they referring to? Does this mean that $\alpha$ has a finite set of ramification indices and we pick the largest? Does it refer somehow to the class number, although how?!

Frantic google searching just returns the definition of a Norm for an ideal, which is explicitly said not to be the same thing.

Would really appreciate anybody who could illuminate this for me.

Comment: The index of an idea in its ring, which is the same as the index of the additive, abelian subgroup $\;\alpha\;$ in its bigger group...

Comment: I am finding the first paragraph in [ideal norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_norm) helpful:

"In commutative algebra, the norm of an ideal is a generalization of a norm of an element in the field extension. It is particularly important in number theory since it measures the size of an ideal of a complicated number ring in terms of an ideal in a less complicated ring. When the less complicated number ring is taken to be the ring of integers, $\mathbb{Z}$, then **the norm of a nonzero ideal $I$ of a number ring $R$ is simply the size of the finite quotient ring $R/I$**."

Comment: Ah, thanks @DonAntonio - I have only seen the notation $|:|$ before for this :)

Comment: If you have seen Lagrange, then you know that $|G|=(G:1)$ and that we have $(G:1)=(G:H)(H:1)$ for a subgroup $H$ of $G$. This is the same notation here for rings.